# Creating a Nested Tree List View in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a class that I would like to use to populate a self-nesting tree style list.  Here is the basic definition:

```
final class Item : Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var brand: String?
    var liked: Bool?
    var notes: String?
    var children: [Item]?

    init(categoryName: String, items: [Item]?) {
        self.name = categoryName
        if let items {
            self.children? = []
            self.children!.insert(contentsOf: items, at: 0)
        }
    }

    init(productName: String, liked: Bool, notes: String) {
        self.name = productName
        self.brand = ""
        self.liked = liked
        self.notes = notes
    }

    init(productName: String, brand: String, liked: Bool, notes: String) {
        self.name = productName
        self.brand = brand
        self.liked = liked
        self.notes = notes
    }
}
```

Even though the goal is to eventually pull this data from JSON or CoreData or something (I'm VERY new), for the purposes of testing, I have manually built some data like so:

```
let item1 = Item(productName: "Crispy Honey Shrimp", brand: "P.F. Changs", liked: true, notes: "Goold flavor and texture")
let item2 = Item(productName: "Bourbon Chicken Pasta (bag)", brand: "Zatarain's", liked: true, notes: "Tasty, easy to make")
let item3 = Item(productName: "Bourbon CHicken Pasta (box)", brand: "Zatarain's", liked: false, notes: "Wrong pasta, bad sauce")
let item4 = Item(productName: "Fries", liked: true, notes: "Well seasoned. Cronch")
let item5 = Item(productName: "Texas Cheesesteak Plate", liked: true, notes: "")
let cat7 = Item(categoryName: "Checker's", items: [item4])
let cat6 = Item(categoryName: "Waffle House", items: [item5])
let cat5 = Item(categoryName: "Fast Food", items: [cat7])
let cat4 = Item(categoryName: "Dine-In", items: [cat6])
let cat3 = Item(categoryName: "Restaraunts", items: [cat4, cat5])
let cat2 = Item(categoryName: "Frozen Food", items: [item1, item2, item3])
let cat1 = Item(categoryName: "Grocery", items: [cat2])
let items = [cat1, cat3]
```

Finally, the view looks like this:

```
struct ItemList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(items, children: \.children) { row in
            HStack {
                Text(row.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The simulator crashes, and it *seems* to have difficulties with the data model? I guess?  Its difficult for me to parse.  A pastebin of the crash report is at https://pastebin.com/mpXdcQ0a

I'm a C# dev, and SwiftUI is a VERY new paradigm for me.  And I'm definitely struggling.  If I am obviously going wrong somewhere - even if its just advice, pointing out anti-patterns, not actual answers to the question - I welcome any knowledge.  Thanks.

Comment: Crash report link doesn't work, you should just post the text of it here. Also, variables should start with a lowercase

Comment: Fixed the link. And thanks for the style tip! :)

Comment: So it's just that line in init where you initialize children. Change it to `if let items {
            self.children = items
        }` - that's all

Comment: In Swift the models are usually structs to take advantage of value semantics which is also how SwiftUI works.

Comment: In addition to recommendation to change `Item` to `struct`, I would also recommend against using a default implementation for the `Identifiable` protocol, as it's changing every time the object with the same properties is initialized. Instead, use ID you get from backend (if there's one), or `name` (if it's globally unique), or combination / hash on properties. That way updates to the list will not cause unwanted redraw of the whole list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this basic approach in SwiftUI, using `struct Item`, with a custom `id` to make it `Identifiable`. Also using a `@State var items: [Item] = []` in the `View` and setting its data in `.onAppear{...}`

```
struct Item : Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {  // <--- here
    let id = UUID()  // <--- here
    
    var name: String
    var brand: String?
    var liked: Bool?
    var notes: String?
    var children: [Item]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {  // <--- here, note no id
        case name,brand,liked,notes,children
    }
    
    init(categoryName: String, items: [Item]?) {
        self.name = categoryName
        if let items {
            self.children = []
            self.children?.append(contentsOf: items)  // <--- here
        }
    }
    
    init(productName: String, liked: Bool, notes: String) {
        self.name = productName
        self.brand = ""
        self.liked = liked
        self.notes = notes
    }
    
    init(productName: String, brand: String, liked: Bool, notes: String) {
        self.name = productName
        self.brand = brand
        self.liked = liked
        self.notes = notes
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [Item] = []  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items, children: \.children) { row in
            HStack {
                Text(row.name)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            let item1 = Item(productName: "Crispy Honey Shrimp", brand: "P.F. Changs", liked: true, notes: "Goold flavor and texture")
            let item2 = Item(productName: "Bourbon Chicken Pasta (bag)", brand: "Zatarain's", liked: true, notes: "Tasty, easy to make")
            let item3 = Item(productName: "Bourbon CHicken Pasta (box)", brand: "Zatarain's", liked: false, notes: "Wrong pasta, bad sauce")
            let item4 = Item(productName: "Fries", liked: true, notes: "Well seasoned. Cronch")
            let item5 = Item(productName: "Texas Cheesesteak Plate", liked: true, notes: "")
            let cat7 = Item(categoryName: "Checker's", items: [item4])
            let cat6 = Item(categoryName: "Waffle House", items: [item5])
            let cat5 = Item(categoryName: "Fast Food", items: [cat7])
            let cat4 = Item(categoryName: "Dine-In", items: [cat6])
            let cat3 = Item(categoryName: "Restaraunts", items: [cat4, cat5])
            let cat2 = Item(categoryName: "Frozen Food", items: [item1, item2, item3])
            let cat1 = Item(categoryName: "Grocery", items: [cat2])
            
            items = [cat1, cat3]  // <--- here
        }
    }
    
}
```

Once you start using persistence, for example [SwiftData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata),
you will have to adjust the code, such as:

`@Model class Item: Codable, Identifiable { ... }`

and in the `View`:

`@Query(sort: \.name, order: .reverse) var items: [Item]`

Comment: These changes absolutely worked, and went from fatal errors to showing the UI the way I hoped and expected it would look.  Thank you!